# Sqlalchemy parent loop query

Tags: sqlalchemy

Parent_id is same table primaty key (id).

[image: Example table]

Lets say i want to get all related to id 2 and itself. I get id 2, 3 and 4. I this kinda relationship query possible? Dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) in SQLAlchemy docs, the suggested model structure is this:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    children = relationship("Node")
```